# Getting Values from Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am making an app that uploads images with some various informations. I can get images from phone gallery and I made a kind of slider where I can fill up the form. In form I have used spinner and textView and my layouts are like this:

details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout_fullscreen_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sizes"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sizes"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sizes"
        android:text="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSizes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sizes"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPieces"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sizes"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Piece/s" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and an action bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_to_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        android:title="@string/cart"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />


</menu>
```

I have an ImageAdapter that shows the images as slider where `layout_fullscreen_image.xml` with this method:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imgDisplay;
    Button btnClose;

    sizes = new ArrayList<String>();
    sizes.add("3x4");
    sizes.add("4x6");
    sizes.add("5x8");

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);

    imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);

    Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.sizes);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this._activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizes);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
    imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

    return viewLayout;
}
```

and a main Class Details.java

```
public class Details extends Activity{

    private ArrayList<String> selectedItems;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        selectedItems = (ArrayList<String>)b.getStringArrayList("selectedItems");

        Log.d("selectedItems",selectedItems.toString());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(Details.this, selectedItems);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.details_action_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_add_to_cart:
                UploadImages();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void UploadImages(){
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sizes);
        String temp = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();     
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

What happens is: When I select multiple images it provides me multiple spinner and textView and I tried to retrieve the values from spinner and textView but it gives me only first values. How can I get all the values set in Spinner and textView

Answer (score 0):

You are saying like  , you are getting a spinner with only one item,, r8 ? I did a code similar to this. But change is , Instead of this:

```
sizes = new ArrayList<String>();
sizes.add("3x4");
sizes.add("4x6");
sizes.add("5x8");
```

I added the string array in strings.xml . Can you try that also ?

Comment: No its not that. I get the list fine. Its like this: if I selected 3 images then it will provide me 3 spinners and I can set all the three spinners but the problem is when I finally want to upload all these three images the spinner value I get is always one not 3 values. I want all those 3 values...

Comment: Which one you are getting ? 1st selected one or last selected one ?

Comment: I am getting the First one only

Comment: ok,, For that spinner upon selection code like this, getSelectedItem().toString() ; and then save the string value into an array. From there you can take the values. I think so.

Comment: And what about the default values? What about if the spinner is selected for two or more than that?

Comment: No need to save upon selection . Save it when you are going to use that spinner.